# How do i reset the system cache of WLAN info?

Tags: c#, network-programming

I am trying to write a WLAN fingerprinting program using NativeWifi in C#. To do this i run a loop to get the wlan information many times and then later use matlab to average / analyze the data.

The problem is that i get all the same values, even as i move about the house, when the program is running. From the internet i've seen that there is a cache that stores the data of available networks. I was wondering if there is a system call which resets this cache.

I have also seen this using the cmd call

> netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid

this gives me the same values until i open the available wifi networks in my OS and if i run it again after, it will give different values.

edit: This system will be for my use only, so i would be comfortable starting over on a linux platform if there is a known library that can handle this for me. I don't even know what to google to even get the information, though. Anything related to "network cache" takes me to help threads of unrelated topics...

I will provide the relevant part of my code below:

```
        public void get_info_instance(StreamWriter file)
        {
                try
                {
                    foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces)
                    {

                        Wlan.WlanBssEntry[] wlanBssEntries = wlanIface.GetNetworkBssList();

                        foreach (Wlan.WlanBssEntry network in wlanBssEntries)
                        {
                            int rss = network.rssi;
                            byte[] macAddr = network.dot11Bssid;
                            string tMac = "";
                            for (int i = 0; i < macAddr.Length; i++)
                            {
                                tMac += macAddr[i].ToString("x2").PadLeft(2, '0').ToUpper();
                            }


                            file.WriteLine("Found network: " + System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(network.dot11Ssid.SSID).ToString());
                            file.WriteLine("Signal: " + network.linkQuality + "%");
                            file.WriteLine("BSS Type: " + network.dot11BssType + ".");
                            file.WriteLine("RSSID: " + rss.ToString());
                            file.WriteLine("BSSID: " + tMac);
                            file.WriteLine(" ");
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                } 
        }
```

Comment: did you try the netsh wlan delete command and see if it refreshes?

Comment: This is the only solution i have found, however it takes a second or longer to execute. This code has to run about an order of magnitude faster to be usable (trying to obtain thousands of grid points.)

Comment: cant go faster then c++ 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry i am a little confused, what is the context of a "profile" in this case? I don't understand what parameters i would send to delete the cached information. Is that information considered a profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, netsh is powered by [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706735(v=vs.85).aspx) API. What this means, is that calling netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid just returns the cache of the networks that showed up during the last scan. This is what you've discovered.

This means that in order to refresh this cache, you need to trigger a scan. If your C# library you are using includes it, you could make this happen on demand with a call to [WlanScan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706783(v=vs.85).aspx). I am not sure which C# wrapper you are using, but it probably includes this function. When you get a [scan complete notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706771(v=vs.85).aspx) (register with source WLAN_NOTIFICATION_SOURCE_ACM and look out for wlan_notification_acm_scan_list_refresh), the cache should be updated.

If you let me know which C# library you are using, maybe I can point you to the relevant functions.

You mentioned that opening the available networks causes the cache to refresh. This is because opening the available networks triggers a call to WlanScan.

Profiles are not relevant to the available network list -- profiles are what the Wlan service uses to keep track of which networks are configured on your machine -- deleting them does not make WlanSvc scan again. It may be a coincidence that deleting them happens to coincide with a scan, but it is more of a side effect than the designed usage.

edit: to subscribe to notifications using the Managed Wifi API you are using, this snippet should work:

```
    wlanIface.WlanNotification += wlanIface_WlanNotification;
```

And the callback:

```
    static void wlanIface_WlanNotification(Wlan.WlanNotificationData notifyData)
    {
        if (notifyData.notificationCode == (int)Wlan.WlanNotificationCodeAcm.ScanComplete)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Scan Complete!");
        }
    }
```

You can test this by running this, then opening the available networks on Windows. You should see "Scan Complete" shortly after you open it each time. You can use a messagebox instead of Console.WriteLine if you prefer.

To trigger a scan yourself:

```
    wlanIface.Scan();
```

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks!! I'm using the [Managed Wifi API](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/) which uses NativeWifi.

Comment: Thumbing through the example, I've found WlanScan. Wlan.WlanScan(client.clientHandle, info.interfaceGuid, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero));
The last 3 arguments are reserved/optional, and for what you want, they should be 0.

Comment: Here is the WlanRegisterNotification call.



Wlan.WlanRegisterNotification(clientHandle, Wlan.WlanNotificationSource.ACM, false, wlanNotificationCallback, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, out prevSrc));
You want to register once in your program. In the callback (wlanNotificationCallback), you want to check if the notificationCode of the WlanNotificationData. I think you are looking for WlanNotificationCodeAcm.ScanComplete.. you really want ScanRefresh, but it looks like the Managed Wifi API is a little outdated.

tbh you are probably fine firing the scan and just waiting a second

Comment: As an aside, should you ever be working on windows 10, there is [this new WiFi API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.wifi.aspx) built into windows that should make this all easier :)

Comment: I'm not sure what i should be sending over in WlanScan the second parameter "info.interfaceGuid" and how to retrieve that?

Comment: If I am looking at the API right, it is a property of the WlanInterface. So in your case, it would be wlanIface.InterfaceGuid. As to what an interfaceGuid is -- every WiFi driver on your system is assigned a GUID by Windows. This API just wants that GUID.

Comment: In fact, taking another look at the API, it looks like each interface has a Scan method you can call that will take care of this for you. Try wlanIface.Scan();

Comment: It looks like they also took care of registering for notification for you. You can just add an event handler to WlanNotificationEventHandler and look for the ScanComplete there if you want to do that. Sorry, I'm not an expert with this API so I think I found the wrong functions the first time.

Comment: I'm just having a little trouble looking for ScanComplete, do i need to actually go change the code in the API itself? because besides that it is working as long as i use a very long delay, because it finishes the scan. But i cannot understand how to let my program know that the scan is complete.

Comment: `wlanIface.WlanNotification += wlanIface_WlanNotification;`

and

`static void wlanIface_WlanNotification(Wlan.WlanNotificationData notifyData)
        {
            if (notifyData.notificationCode == (int)Wlan.WlanNotificationCodeAcm.ScanComplete)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Scan Complete!");
            }
        }` I will add this to the original post

Answer (score 0):

for all

```
netsh wlan delete profile name=* i=*
```

you might not want to do it on all interfaces, and hard code the interface in there for faster result

Comment: The first time i used this, it worked! but when i 
netsh wlan show networks 
again, then 
netsh wlan delete profile name=* i=*,

a second time, i get the following message:
Profile * is not found on any interfaces.

This occurs until i reconnect to my internet.

Comment: the next command you want to do is probably do the netsh cmd to connect , and then run your code above in your question